# Comparing MYSQL timestamps to retrieve time passed in specific units

Tags: php, mysql, math, time

Here is a PHP function I have designed, which is supposed to determine the amount of time passed in secs,mins,hours,days,weeks,months, and years - depending upon which bracket it is beneath. However Ive noticed that the values being returned seem to increase faster than actual time (within 30 mins, it outputs "1 weeks ago"). Im wondering if `$time` is actually in millis? That said, for the first 2 mins it outputs relatively accurate results.

*Note: Running on 1and1 host.*

**Here's the function:**

```
function get_relative_date($conn,$date,$post_id){
    #get current timestamp
    $q = "SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR - `timestamp` FROM `posts` WHERE id=".$post_id.";";
    # - INTERVAL 1 HOUR added due to server running 1 hour ahead.
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
    if ($result != null && $result != false){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
        $time = $row[0];    #time passed since post

        $min = 60;
        $hour = $min*60;
        $day = $hour*24;
        $week = $day*7;
        $month = $week*4;
        $year = $month*12;

        if ($time < $min){
            return $time." secs ago";
        }
        if ($time < $hour){
            return round(($time / $min))." mins ago";
        }
        if ($time < $day){
            return round(($time / $hour))." hours ago";
        }
        if ($time < $week){
            return round(($time / $day))." days ago";
        }
        if ($time < $month){
            return round(($time / $week))." weeks ago";
        }
        if ($time < $year){
            return round(($time / $month))." months ago";
        }
        if ($time >= $year){
            return round(($time / $year))." years ago.";
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your query out  and instead of 2 minutes and 40 seconds (in seconds) I was receiving 240 and instead of 1 hour 3 minutes and 40 seconds (in seconds) I got 10340.

You need this:

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),`timestamp`)) FROM `posts` ...
```

This will select the time difference in seconds and hopefully give you the desired result.

Comment: Ahhh I see, my query wasn't actually comparing the correct values needed, cheers this works beautifully.